# Passing lambda function to a SYCL parallel for region

Tags: c++, lambda, intel-oneapi, sycl

A SYCL kernel can be submitted to a `queue` as follows -

```
Queue.submit([=](handler& cgh){
        cgh.parallel_for<class test>(_range, [=](nd_item<2> iter{
      Write your function (F) here. 
});
    });
```

Now, the above mentioned function F is accepted as a lambda and I want to the something as follows -

```
void deviceManager::dispatchFunction(const T CGF, nd_range<2> _range){
    this->Queue.submit([=](handler& cgh){
        cgh.parallel_for<class test>(_range, CGF);
    });
```

Where `CGF` is the lamda function being passed as the parameter. I am calling it as follows -

```
    int y = 0;
    int z = 10;
    int x = -2394801;

    deviceManager manager;   
    manager.dispatchFunction([=]() -> void {
        printf("Printf from lambda  | %d = \n", x);
        printf("Y = %d | Z = %d \n", y, y + z);
    }, nd_range<2>(range<2>(4, 4), range<2>(2, 2)));
```

However, I get the following error -

```
In file included from testSYCL.cpp:4:
In file included from /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/backend.hpp:18:
In file included from /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/backend_traits_opencl.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/queue.hpp:20:
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:1112:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const (lambda at testSYCL.cpp:141:30)'
    KernelFunc(detail::Builder::getElement(detail::declptr<ElementType>()));
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:1232:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sycl::handler::kernel_parallel_for<test, sycl::nd_item<2>, (lambda at testSYCL.cpp:141:30)>' requested here
    kernel_parallel_for<KernelName, ElementType>(KernelFunc);
    ^
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:1568:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sycl::handler::kernel_parallel_for_wrapper<test, sycl::nd_item<2>, (lambda at testSYCL.cpp:141:30)>' requested here
    kernel_parallel_for_wrapper<NameT, TransformedArgType>(KernelFunc);
    ^
testSYCL.cpp:124:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sycl::handler::parallel_for<test, (lambda at testSYCL.cpp:141:30), 2>' requested here
        cgh.parallel_for<class test>(_range, CGF);
            ^
testSYCL.cpp:141:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'deviceManager::dispatchFunction<(lambda at testSYCL.cpp:141:30)>' requested here
    manager.dispatchFunction([=]() -> void {
            ^
testSYCL.cpp:141:30: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    manager.dispatchFunction([=]() -> void {
                             ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `void deviceManager::dispatchFunction(const T CGF, ...` - what is `T`?

Comment: In your first example the inner function takes an argument `nd_item<2> iter` that is missing from the function in the second argument

Comment: Your lambda suppose to accept one argument, you are trying to pass a lambda without any.

Answer (score 0):

SYCL kernel function that is passed to `sycl::handler::parallel_for()` should have at least one argument of [`index space class`](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#index-space-classes). Therefore, as @Artyer and @Slava
mentioned in the comments, the lambda function should have at least one argument even if it is not used:

```cpp
    manager.dispatchFunction([=](cl::sycl::nd_item<2>) -> void {
        printf("Printf from lambda  | %d = \n", x);
        printf("Y = %d | Z = %d \n", y, y + z);
    }, nd_range<2>(range<2>(4, 4), range<2>(2, 2)));
```

Next, SYCL does not support the call of `printf()` function in the device code. It is necessary to use `sycl::stream` instead of it (please see [C.10.4. printf function](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#_printf_function) section). Here is a short example, that is based on the code from the question:

```cpp
class DeviceManager {
public:
    DeviceManager(const sycl::device_selector& d_selector)
        : m_queue(d_selector)
    {}

    template<typename Func, int N>
    void dispatchFunction(Func func, const cl::sycl::nd_range<N>& range) {
        m_queue.submit([=](cl::sycl::handler& cgh) {
            cl::sycl::stream out(1024, 256, cgh);
            cgh.parallel_for(range, [=](cl::sycl::nd_item<N> iter) {
                std::invoke(func, iter, out);
            });
        });
    }

    void wait() {
        m_queue.wait();
    }

private:
    cl::sycl::queue m_queue;
};

int main() {
    DeviceManager deviceManager((cl::sycl::default_selector()));

    int y = 0;
    int z = 10;
    int x = -2394801;

    deviceManager.dispatchFunction([=](cl::sycl::nd_item<2>, cl::sycl::stream sout) {
        sout << "Printf from lambda  | " << x << " = \n";
        sout << "Y = " << y << " | Z = " << y + z << "\n";
    }, cl::sycl::nd_range<2>(cl::sycl::range<2>(4, 4), cl::sycl::range<2>(2, 2)));
    deviceManager.wait();
}
```